# Spring Boot in WebLogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

We are trying to use spring boot embedded server for development and weblogic for production.  Seems like this should be easy as a war file is easy to produce and should work in any container - just like the java mantra of write once, run anywhere.  So far has been a major pain and not sure it is really possible.

If anyone has some insight, I would love to hear from you.

I'm having a terrible time trying to get a spring boot app to work in a web logic container.  Weblogic 12.2.1  (NOTE this is the latest release of Weblogic)

1. Issue 1 - for some reason web logic wants to load the
   JerseyServletContainerInitializer.  This causes a class not found
   exception and can not get any further.  My kludge, write a new
   JerseyServletContainerInitializer (with the correct package) and
   deploy with my code.  gets me past the class not found issue into
   spring code.

   Issue 2 - slf4j finds multiple implementations - the extra one is
   from WebLogic which can not be removed (others apps on the server
   use it) but that is the only solution according to SLF4j.    Not at
   all helpful.

   Issue 3 - Weblogic provides multiple persistent providers which
   spring seems to find and try and map the eclipse persistence
   provider rather than the the hibernate provider.  (We are not using
   a persistence.xml).  this results in java.lang.ClassCastException:
   org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to
   javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
        at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1612)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1597)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:609)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:580)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:524)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:492)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:457)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:407)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:205)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:852)
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.validate(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:350)
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:271)
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:241)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:         334)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:         289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
```

My weblogic.xml looks like

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
>       http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
>       http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
>
> ```
> <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
> <wls:context-root>ola/</wls:context-root>
>  <wls:container-descriptor>
>     <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
>
>     <wls:prefer-application-packages>
>         <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>javassist.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>javax.annotation.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
>         <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.tiger_types.*</wls:package-name>
>     </wls:prefer-application-packages>
>
> </wls:container-descriptor>
> ```

I am trying to NOT use a web.xml.

My main class is

```
    package com.cc.ola.launch;

    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
    import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableMBeanExport;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
    import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

    @Profile("test")
    @Configuration
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.cc")
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.cc.ola")
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.cc.ola" })
    @EnableCaching
    @EnableJms
    @EnableMBeanExport
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
    public class LaunchFromWebLogic extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            System.out.println("loading spring application");
            return application.sources(LaunchFromWebLogic.class);
        }
    }
```

I've read all of the docs I can find dozens of times.

I've tried the sample code @ https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs.git
which deploys but doesn't work either

Comment: Did your main class implemented webApplicatioinitializee. Example will be like  public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer { }

Comment: I guess you've checked [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-weblogic) already?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution to your SLF4J issue. In your weblogic.xml, add the following tag under your container-descriptor tag:

```
<prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>
```

I'm also using 12.2.1 and although I still cannot get it to work for different reasons, I did not face the persistence provider problem. In my case, weblogic picked up Hibernate 5 without issues. Are you using the spring starters in your POM? Which version of Boot are you using?

Perhaps add your POM to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Although a year and a half ago, I'll just provide an answer in case anyone else gets here with this problem.

The problem probably comes from some `@Valid` annotation on the call, i.e. the stacktrace shows that it performs some pre-method validation using Hibernate Validator library.

The validator check if class is loaded using `javax.persistence.Persistence`, which delegates to a `PersistenceProviderContextHolder` to find the `PersistenceProvider`. The default one inspects the services defined in */META-INF/services* and finds two (eclipse and hibernate) and returns the first (!).

Using the tip in this question ([Weblogic 10.3.3 trying to load org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider instead of configured Hibernate Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806457/weblogic-10-3-3-trying-to-load-org-eclipse-persistence-jpa-persistenceprovider-i)) and providing a new `PersistenceProviderContextHolder` which only returns Hibernate will therefore do the trick. However, it would be good to deregister on `contextClosed` by setting it to null.