# bean validation does not work under weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

The title is inspecific, sorry, but I don't know what's really wrong ...

Ok, so I have working springboot app (version 2.0.4.RELEASE), weblogic 12.2.1.1. When running standalone, it's OK. But when executed under weblogic, beanvalidation silently ignores all validation issues. The typical weblogic cause for this is, that it ignores libraries which apps wants, and using it's own instead resulting in unexpected and unreliable app behavior. And yes, when debugging, bean validation code does not match with what is being declared in pom.xml. So I added

```
   <package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</package-name>
   <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
```

as `prefer-application-packages`, but now I'm getting

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

which was described here: [Weblogic 10.3.3 trying to load org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider instead of configured Hibernate Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806457/weblogic-10-3-3-trying-to-load-org-eclipse-persistence-jpa-persistenceprovider-i) but I cannot get it to work. Any help please? I understand, that this means that weblogic is probably ruining foundations of springboot app, I'd like to fix it, however it kinda works, except for beanvalidation. So complete fix is probably not that necessary, and maybe someone does have an idea how to differently pretty-please weblogic to turn bean validation on?

I'd really like to share more, but that thing does not log any issue at all. It just dont validate beans, and the same code (except for weblogic tooling) does work properly, when weblogic is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

There must be following in weblogic.xml

```
...
<prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider</resource-name>
    ...
</prefer-application-resources>
...
```